# What's the difference between "app" and "backend" in yii

Tags: php, yii2

what's the difference between these two lines of codes?  do they refer to a same place?

```
use app\models\EntryForm;  
use backend\models\EntryForm;
```

I'm using the advanced yii2
and in the yii tutorial it just uses `app` and I think that's because it's talking about the basic yii version. but as I said what are the differences? should I only use `backend` while using the advanced version and `app` is not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the names `app` or `backend` or `frontend`   are names of an application ..

if you are using advanced  template .. you should refer to the related application using   for backend

```
use backend\models\EntryForm;
```

and the namespace  definition you should use  eg:

```
namespace backend\models\;
```

or  for frontend

```
use frontend\models\EntryForm; 

namespace frontend\models\;
```

for common  part you can use

```
   common\models

   use common\models\EntryForm;
```

The structure is related to the https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md

Comment: and how about the `app`? is it only for basic version?

Comment: Yes normally is the conventional  application name for basic version  .. is often used like alias by someone ..

Comment: The structure of the path is related to https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md